# SQL formula for Row number

Tags: sql, row, rank, row-number

I'm trying to rank the rows in the following table that looks like this:

```
| ID   | Key    | Date   | Row|
*****************************
| P175 |  5     | 2017-01| 2  |
| P175 |  5     | 2017-02| 2  |
| P175 |  5     | 2017-03| 2  |
| P175 |  12    | 2017-03| 1  |
| P175 |  12    | 2017-04| 1  |
| P175 |  12    | 2017-05| 1  |
```

This person has two Keys at once during 2017-03, but I want the formula to put '1' for the rows where Key=12 since it reflects the most recent records.

I want the same formula to also work for the people who don't have overlapping Keys, putting '1' for the most recent records:

```
| ID   | Key    | Date   | Row|
*****************************
| P170 |  8     | 2017-01| 2  |
| P170 |  8     | 2017-02| 2  |
| P170 |  8     | 2017-03| 2  |
| P170 |  6     | 2017-04| 1  |
| P170 |  6     | 2017-05| 1  |
```

I've tried variations of ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY and DENSE_RANK but cannot figure out the correct formula. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ur sample data is confusing....

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @MigsIsip I'm using ssms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the max date for the key.  Then use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by max_date desc, key) as row
from (select t.*, max(date) over (partition by id, key) as max_date
      from t
     ) t;
```

If the ranges for each key did not overlap, you could do this with a cumulative count distinct:

```
select t.*, count(distinct key) over (partition by id order by date desc) as rank
from t;
```

However, this would not work in the first case.  I just find it interesting that this does almost the same thing as the first query.

Comment: I tried this and it works for some but not all records - if a person has 2 keys at the same time where the most recent dates are also the same, they all show up as 1. In this case it wouldn't matter which key gets a 1 or 2 since they are both most recent. Do you know a way around this? Thank you.

Comment: @Joyce . . . That should be easy to fix.  Just add `key` as the last column in the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this

```
select personid, mykey, month,
       dense_rank() over (partition by personid order by mykey desc) rown
from personkeys
order by month
```

see the example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf751/8